# SVG as labels in HighChart stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a stacked column chart in highchart, with the x-axis labels being SVG-images as shown on this image:

[image]

I've gotten it to work with single data points per label (ie non-stacked data), but as soon I change the input data to an array, the data stops rendering.
This "works":
https://jsfiddle.net/jakobhl/krx4e5pm/2/

```js
var dataName = function(imgSrc) {
  return '<span><img src=' + imgSrc + ' ' + 'style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"/><br></span>';
};

var data2016 = [
  [11, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197571.svg")],
  [11, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197408.svg")],
  [11, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197375.svg")],
  [14, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197374.svg")],
  [12, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197484.svg")],
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0,
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      align: 'center'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    keys: ['y', 'name'],
    data: data2016,
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

This does not:
https://jsfiddle.net/jakobhl/2rfa645x/3/

```js
var dataName = function(imgSrc) {
  return '<span><img src=' + imgSrc + ' ' + 'style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"/><br></span>';
};

var data2016 = [
  [[11, 15], dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197571.svg")],
  [[12, 15], dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197408.svg")],
  [[13, 15], dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197375.svg")],
  [[41, 15], dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197374.svg")],
  [[11, 15], dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197484.svg")],
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0,
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      align: 'center'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    keys: ['y', 'name'],
    data: data2016,
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

How can I get the data to stack per country while still using SVGs as labels?

Thanks to the jsfiddle user BlackLabel for inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out why the original solution didn't work, but a working solution was to use categories instead of series:
https://jsfiddle.net/jakobhl/L3hzeqpv/1/

```js
var dataName = function(imgSrc) {
  return '<span><img src=' + imgSrc + ' ' + 'style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"/><br></span>';
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      align: 'center'
    },
        categories: [dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197571.svg"), dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197408.svg"), dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197375.svg"), dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197374.svg"), dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197484.svg")]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: ( // theme
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                ) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another value, but you need to adapt the data format required by Highcharts. If the new value is `x`, just do it as below:

```
var data2016 = [
    [
        11, 15, dataName("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197571.svg")
    ],
    ...
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        keys: ['y', 'x', 'name'],
        data: data2016
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vubjn8od/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.keys

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, sadly that doesn't quite work, since it groups all the data on the first country (the US in this case). Any ideas how to get get all the countries to show with their respective data?

Comment: Hi @Jakob Handberg Lystbæk, I am sorry, but I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. For example what should represent the values `[11, 15]`?

Comment: [11,15] should result in a stacked column with the values 11 and 15, totaling 26. Your suggestion achieves this, but does not show a column for each county/svg, instead it puts all the values on the first country / svg. I've updated my post with an image of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!